# New Android L material design is not visible in Eclipse Layout Editor

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

At the moment I'm testing the new Android L API Preview. For this I use Eclipse. Is it right that the new material design is not visible in the layout editor at the moment? I do not own a Nexus 5 so I can not install the preview image on my phone and I have to use the emulator for testing the new styles. Is there a way to display the new styles in the layout editor in Eclipse or Android Studio? For example the shadows and so on are not visible at the editor.

So does this work for you in the layout editor and only on my machine it is not working or is the layout editor not updated yet? Do you have any ideas what I can try because to test all this in an emulator is really annoying.

Comment: Have you tried Android Studio yet? It got an update these days from 0.6 to 0.8, I'm sure it's something to do with the L preview release.

Comment: Yes I tried the new version of Android Studio but there is the same problem - no preview from shadow or something else in the layout editor.

Comment: Shadows require hardware rendering and won't show up in the layout editor.